# Problem I.3.3(c) in Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Problem I.3.3(c) from Hartshorne says that if $\phi: X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of varieties and if $\phi(X)$ is dense in $Y$ then the homomorphism of local rings $\phi_P^* : \mathcal{O}_{Y,\phi(P)} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ is injective for every $P \in X$.

Here is how i tried to prove that:

Fact 1: Take $P \in X$ and let $\langle V, f \rangle$ be a non-zero germ at $\phi(P)$. That means that for every neighborhood $W$ of $\phi(P)$, $f$ is non-zero on $W \cap V$.
Suppose now that $\phi_P^*(\langle V, f \rangle) = 0$. By definition of $\phi_P^*$ (if i understand correctly) this means that $\langle \phi^{-1}(V), f \circ \phi \rangle = 0$, and this means that there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $P$ such that $f \circ \phi$ is zero on $\phi^{-1}(V) \cap U$.

Fact 2 (edited after comments): Since $V$ is a neighborhood of $\phi(P)$ and $f$ is non-zero on $V$, there exists some $\xi \in V$ such that $f(\xi) \neq 0$. Since $\phi(X)$ is dense in $Y$, we must have that $\xi$ is a limit point of $\phi(X)$, i.e. for every neighborhood $W$ of $\xi$ we have $\phi(X) \cap W \neq \emptyset$.

> Question 1: Is there a way to combine Facts 1 and 2 to arrive at a proof?
>
> Question 2: I found some hints online saying very concisely that "if $\phi_P^*(f)=0$, then $f$ vanishes on the dense set $V \cap \phi(X)$ and so $f$ must be zero on $V$." I do see why $V \cap \phi(X)$ is dense in $V$ but i don't see why $f$ vanishes on $V \cap \phi(X)$. (In the hint there is no mention of what $V$ is, i assume it is some neighborhood of $\phi(P)$.) I would like an explanation of this hint.

PS: An instructive answer to question 2 will be enough.

Comment: Actually there is a net (not a sequence), unless you have a enumerable local basis for the topology, but since it's the Zariski topology...

Comment: @user40276: Sorry, i don't have a clue what a net is. Also, i thought that all definitions from general topology apply to the Zariski topology. So why would the definition of a limit point be different?

Comment: What you are saying that is the definition of a limit point does not apply to general topological spaces, you must use just open sets. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point

Comment: @user40276: Great thanks. Any ideas about the problem itself?

Comment: Furthermore your question two is just a consequence of the definition of the stalk, because being zero in the stalk is the same as the existence of an open neighborhood $U$ (of $P$, in your case) such that it vanishes identically on $U$.

Comment: @user40276: What we have is that the germ (or stalk) $\langle \phi^{-1} (V), f \circ \phi \rangle$ is zero and this gives that $f \circ \phi$ is zero on $\phi^{-1}(V) \cap U$ for some neighborhood $U$ of $P$. How do we go from this to $f$ being zero on $\phi(X) \cap V$ is what i don't see.

Comment: Maybe you don't know the fact that two morphisms that coincides in an open set are equal…

Comment: @user40276: I know this fact. I also see that $f$ is zero on $\phi(\phi^{-1}(V) \cap U) = V \cap \phi(U)$. Then?

Comment: Well, $f = 0$ in $\phi (U)$ for some neighborhood of $P$, $U$, then $f$ cannot be different from $0$, because $\phi (X)$ is contained in the zeros of $f$ and $\phi (X)$ is dense in $Y$.

Comment: @user40276: Wow, i finally got it. Thanks for your help. If you would like to post your comments as answer i will gladly accept them.